# List of lists to store in MongoDB

Tags: python, python-2.7, pymongo

I have below a list which I stored in a nested `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

if __name__ == "__main__":

r = [["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'G', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'X', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 6]]

s = defaultdict(lambda:
        defaultdict(lambda:
                defaultdict(lambda:
                    defaultdict(lambda:
                            defaultdict(lambda:
                                defaultdict(lambda:
                                        defaultdict(defaultdict)))))))

for i in r:
    s[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]][i[3]][i[4]][i[5]][i[6]] = i[7]
```

But, I am not sure how to convert the above nested defaultdict to a Dict/JSON (see below) so it can be stored to MongoDB.

```
{
type: "Test", 
name: "A", 
sub_name: "B01", 
pos: 828288,  
s_type: 1,    
x_type: 7, 
chr = {
      'C': 5
      'T': 6
      }
}
```

Is there maybe a way to avoid to create a nested defaultdict and store directly each element to MongoDB and apply an update?

**Update**: For the first list it should be `'chr': { 'i[6]': i[7]}` which should give `'chr': { 'C': 5}`. 
For the second list which is only different on last two elements compare to the first list. 
I wanted to add `'T', 6` to the previous `chr` to get `'chr': { 'C': 5, 'T', 6}`.
I created the nested `defaultdict` in order to combine the same elements and the last two elements which are different I wanted to store them in chr dict.

Answer (score 1):

For what reason are you creating that nested defaultdict structure? Do you require quick lookups of each key? If you are saving in Mongo, why not let Mongo do the lookup for you by creating an index for the important fields.

I would simply do the following:

```
r = [["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'G', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'X', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 6]]

for i in r:
    d = {
        'type': i[0],
        'name': i[1],
        'sub_name': i[2],
        'pos': i[3],
        's_type': i[4],
        'x_type': i[5],
        'chr': { 'C': i[6], 'T': i[7]}
    }
    #now save dictionary "d" into mongo.
```

Comment: Almost, for the first list it should be `'chr': { 'i[6]': i[7]}` which should give `'chr': { 'C': 5}`. 
For the second list which is only different on last two elements compare to the first list. 
I wanted to add `'T', 6` to add it to the previous `chr` to get `'chr': { 'C': 5, 'T', 6}`.
I created it in order to combine the same elements and the last two elements which are different 
I wanted to store them in chr dict.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from pymongo import MongoClient
from collections import defaultdict



db = MongoClient().test
sDB = db.sss

r = [["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 828288,  1,    7, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'C', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 171878,  3,    8, 'T', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 871963,  3,    9, 'G', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'A', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 1932523, 1,   10, 'X', 6],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'T', 4],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 5],
    ["Test", "A", "B01", 667214,  1,   14, 'G', 6]]

for i in r:
    d = {
    'type': i[0],
    'name': i[1],
    'sub_name': i[2],
    'pos': i[3],
    's_type': i[4],
    'x_type': i[5],
    'chr': { i[6]: i[7]}
    }
    sDB.update({"x_type": i[5]}, {"$push": {"chr":{i[6]: i[7]} }}, True)
```